# How to invoke a method in a separate thread and use the return status

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, c++11, post

I have a class with one method which sends a `POST` request to a host with file(s) attached (and delete the file(s) once the request has been made). This is the barebone code:

```
using namespace Poco;
using namespace Poco::Net;

FileUploader::FileUploader(std::string aPathToFile): fPathToFile(aPathToFile)
{
}

void FileUploader::uploadFileInSeparateThread()
{
    std::thread([&](){
        this->uploadFile();
    }).detach();
}

bool FileUploader::uploadFile()
{
    try {
        const Context::Ptr context(new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "~/Desktop/root.pem",Context::VERIFY_ONCE));
        Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession httpsSession(HOST, 443,context);

        HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/path/to/service?key=<name_of_file_to_be_uploaded>", HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
        request.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setKeepAlive(true);
        HTMLForm form;
        form.setEncoding(HTMLForm::ENCODING_MULTIPART);
        form.addPart("file", new FilePartSource(fPathToFile));
        form.prepareSubmit(request);

        httpsSession.setKeepAlive(true);
        httpsSession.setTimeout(Poco::Timespan(20, 0));
        form.write(httpsSession.sendRequest(request));

        Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;
        std::istream &is = httpsSession.receiveResponse(res);
        Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(is, std::cout);
        qDebug() << "Message: " << is.rdbuf() << endl;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception &ex)
    {
        qDebug() << "Damn: " << ex.displayText().c_str() << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I invoke the class like this:

```
FileUploader uploader(tempfilePath.toStdString());
uploader.uploadFile();
```

It works fine, however, while the request is ongoing, UI is blocked. So I decided to mutithread it and created a new method `uploadFileInSeparataeThread`. Then I just call

```
FileUploader *uploader = new FileUploader(tempfilePath.toStdString());
uploader->uploadFileInSeparataeThread();
```

This works fine, but problem is, the memory occupied by `uploader` is never deleted. So I made it a unique pointer instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<FileUploader> uploader(new FileUploader(tempfilePath.toStdString()));
uploader->uploadFileInSeparataeThread();
```

This doesn't work, I get a `Damn, file does not exist` error, which happens when the file I am trying to upload in the `form.addPart("file", new FilePartSource(fPathToFile));` part is missing. This is probably expected, unique pointer will go out of scope the moment the invoking method ends. So I tried this:

```
FileUploader uploader(tempfilePath.toStdString());
std::thread thread([&] (FileUploader * newUploader) { newUploader->uploadFile(); }, &uploader);
thread.join();
```

Now this works, but it is not multithreaded, UI is still blocked when the request is ongoing.

How do I make it properly multithreaded, and use the return value from `uploadFile()` to delete the temp file being uploaded once the `POST` request has been made successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last attempt:
Why do you call std::thread::join() right after creating the thread? It makes the primary thread wait until the other thread ends. Call join() only when the uploadFile() method ends (in some other place in code, where you check what is the outcome of the function you called asynchronously), otherwise it will wait.

You can learn that it exited for example by setting some variable when it exits or raising some signal, just somehow informing the UI that it's over and the thread can be joined without forcing the wait.

Comment: `Call join() only when the uploadFile() method exits, otherwise it will wait.` Meaning? How do I invoke the method then

Comment: The method that creates the thread should continue and later somehow learn that the method exited (setting a variable or using a signal) and then call join(). It can't be simply done on a single short block of code.

Comment: What do you mean by `method exists`? Should I just call `std::thread thread([&] (FileUploader * newUploader) { newUploader->uploadFile(); }, &uploader);` and continue?

Comment: I wrote method exits, not method exists, without the 's' before 'ts'. Check if the execution has exited. And yes, you should just call that line and continue, and return to joining the thread later, most conveniently when you want to read the result it came to.

Comment: If I omit that line, the app just crashes.

Comment: Just crashes? Where does it crash? It can't crash on an omitted line. You must be accessing something that isn't available yet because the other thread has not written it. Use a debugger or some logs to locate the line where it crashes.

Comment: That is the exact like that crashes it. Logs show this stack call: `std::__1::thread::~thread()` -> `std::terminate()` -> `std::__terminate(void (*)())` -> `default_terminate_handler()` -> `abort_message` -> `abort`. I swear outside what I have shown here, there is nothing else that is going on, so I cannot say who is accessing what that is not supposed to be accessed.

Comment: Wait... the thread object is local. When its scope ends, it is automatically destroyed and you can't destroy a thread that is running. Allocate it dynamically and destroy it somewhere later.

Comment: Well, that really takes us back to the second method, which was working fine, only the freeing of allocated resource was hindering me. How do I determine when the uploading has finished?

Comment: Why did you use `std::unique_ptr` there anyway? `std::shared_ptr` should do the job, the object held is destroyed when the last copy of the `shared_ptr` object is destroyed.

Comment: So when is that? When the thread finishes executing, i.e that method which uploads file, the shared pointer will be auto deleted?

Comment: If that is where the last copy of the `shared_ptr` object vanishes, then yes.

Comment: The shared pointer will be allocated locally (just inside the method where I need to invoke the uploader). So perhaps that is the last copy?

Comment: If you don't keep a copy elsewhere, then it is.

Comment: Nope. Same result. File not found.. :(

Comment: I can't know what's the problem because I don't see the header of the object. You could try to print the contents of the fPathToFile variable.

Comment: Are you sure that it works correctly without that `shared_ptr` to deallocate memory? In both cases, you are calling the `filePartSource` constructor with the same argument, what can be different there?

Comment: Hmm, that stumped me as well. I can understand it with `unique_ptr`, but it should not happens with `shared_ptr`... :(

Comment: Does the networking environment you're using support multithreading? If it does not, undefined behaviour issues of all kinds happen when you the least expect it.